# PHP receive json

Tags: php, ajax, json, knockout.js

I'm using knockout and this is my ajax code:

```
save: function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"http://localhost/loyalty/welcome/json/",
                    type: "post",
                    data: ko.toJSON(this),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (result) { alert(result) }
                });
            }
```

Using firebug I can see that the json message is sent correctly, the problem is how to receive it on PHP, what is the name of what has been sent?

I'm using CodeIgniter

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to take

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

from ajax call.

=)

Answer (score 2):

It would be in the variable `$_POST['key']` where `'key'` is the key values in the JSON object.

Comment: Hi...I'm receiving this JSON: [{"name":"JoÃ£o","isOnTwitter":false}] and using $_POST['name'] returns nothing.

Comment: Your JSON is in an array. You would want it in a bare object with just the `{}` around it. Otherwise it is an array, and you would need to give it a name. Something like `{"jsonval":ko.toJSON(this)}`

Comment: form data is not passed using json. HTTP has its own format to transfer data. Use form.serialize()

Comment: How do I return only JSON instead of a array?

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee The `data` value in the jQuery ajax function can be passed via an object format like listed. Serialization is another way to do it and is also valid

Comment: @Gerep It would depend on your object and the `toJSON` method. If you want, we can take this to [chat] so this discussion doesn't go on too long, but I can't chat for long. Anyone in JS chat can probably help too

Comment: So, according to [ko documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) `.toJSON` converts it to a string value. Instead, just pass the object itself in the `data` variable and jQuery should convert it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7703/discussion-between-gerep-and-ktash)

Comment: I just had a similar problem with the extra quotes in the JavaScript object.  I fixed the issue by using `ko.toJS` instead of `ko.toJSON`.

Answer (score 2):

```
    **This is what exactly the way to post as json way**

//index.php
     $(document).ready(function(){
               obj = {}
               obj.name = "sam"
               obj.value = "12345"
                      $.ajax({
                               url:"json.php",
                               type: "post",
                               data :obj,
                               dataType:"json",
                               success: function (result) {
                                    alert(result.name);
                               }
                             });
            }); 

    //json.php  ,, the posted data is received as array ,, so we need to convert it as //json_encode to make as JSON again 

    <?php
    $jsonReceiveData = json_encode($_POST);
    echo $jsonReceiveData;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  save: function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://localhost/loyalty/welcome/json/",
                type: "post",
                data: $(this).serialize()/*Where this is an instance of the form change with appropriate selector such as #loginForm*/,
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (result) { alert(result) }
            });
        }
```

Use $_POST in the php file to get the data
I am assumin you are using jquery as well and $ is the jquery function. Now this data is available in the post superglobal. NB: you need not use json to send data through the ajax function. Data is passsed in a serialized array format like: field1=value1&field2=value2 etc...

If you must however use json, which frankly is unnecessary, use data:"json="+ko.toJSON(form)

and on server side data=json_decode($_POST['json']);