# Send JSON from Java to PHP through Post

Tags: java, php, android

I am doing an Android program that is supposed to send data from the tablet to a PHP Web Service. The code for sending the JSON:

```
package com.example.shvalidation;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainMenuScreen extends Activity {
    //JSON Variables
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    String pid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu_layout);
        new TestThread().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu_layout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void PlantToDome(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectLocationScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    //Código del Web Service
    public class TestThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainMenuScreen.this, "Loading", "Loading data, please wait..");
        }

        private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void...args0) {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response;
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.101:8080/GetBook.php");

                JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject euid = new JSONObject();
                euid.put("euid", 1);
                holder.accumulate("euids", euid);
                euid.put("euid", 2);
                holder.accumulate("euids", euid);

                post.setHeader("json", holder.toString());
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());
                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                response = client.execute(post);
                if (response != null) {
                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();

                    String a = convertStreamToString(in);
                    Log.i("Read from Server", a);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("error", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

The PHP Web Service:

```
<?php
    ob_start();

    var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')));

    $out = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    $f = fopen('out.txt', 'w+');

    fwrite($f, html_entity_decode($out));

    fclose($f);
?>
```

I have tried different methods for getting the JSON, but none of them have worked for me. Maybe the fine people of StackOverflow can help me out with this, as they always have for every other problem that I've had.

Comment: Why would you put the json in a HTTP header?

Comment: I have just been following tutorials on the internet since this is the first time doing a Web Service.

Comment: It really should be a POST with JSON as ... something that was posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181534/http-post-using-json-in-java

Comment: THen on the PHP side you parse the POST: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280970/php-receive-json

Comment: I get the data correctly now. It returns this: 

`string '{"euids":[{"euid":1},{"euid":2}]}' (length=33)`

However I just want the JSON, not the additional data like string in the beginning or length at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comments section, it appears you only want the JSON being sent to your PHP script. Normally, you post POST  this to PHP, and extract it:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
    $json_string = $_POST['message']; 
    $json = json_decode($json_string);
    print_r($json);
?>
```

And then a small client example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String json = "{\"message\":\"This is a message\"}";

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://somesite.com/test.php");
        StringEntity params =new StringEntity("message=" + json);
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        // handle response here...

        System.out.println(org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle exception here
    } finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
Array
(
    [message] => {"message":"This is a message"}
)
stdClass Object
(
    [message] => This is a message
)
```