# Sending Json message using gson on android

Tags: android, json, http, gson, send

I want to send a json message over http to a php server.I used the gson library as you can see.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String[] data = {"value1", "value2", "value3"};
String json = gson.toJson(data);
String message = "jdata"+json; //I did this because of the server implementation 
String path= "http://localhost/joomla/index.php?option=com_up1";
```

I want to connect to send (POST) the string **message** to the server that is located on the **path**
The server will retrieve the **values, value1,value2,value3** from the message.

```
$jd = json_decode(JRequest::getVar( 'jdata'), true);
if (sizeof($jd)>0) {


$name = $jd[0];
$surname = $jd[1];
......
 ......
```

The server will return messages like

```
if ($db->query()) {
                printf("OK");
```

that I want to display in my application.

How can I send the message to the server ?
And how can I read the messages from the server to my app ?

Comment: How can I send json message  using gson ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send JSON from Java to PHP through Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983521/send-json-from-java-to-php-through-post)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In android long operation such as internet interaction should (in latest versions **must**) be done in separate thread.

You can accomplish this task in many ways, but i think the simplest consists in creating a subclass of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and put the network interaction into the `doInBackground` method. To interact with the server you can use either the Apache [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) or the [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Comment: -1: I disagree. Consider an IntentService. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4177349/109941

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [HttpPost](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) class. A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20httppost) will show you tons of examples.

Comment: I have found many examples but none of them explains the steps that are taken to complete HTTP POST.... I could not understand how it works

Comment: Refine the google search to "android httppost json". One of the first results is this one, it does exactly what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218143/android-post-json-using-http

Answer (score 0):

You say you want it in the path but:

```
//If it's a parameter it would have to be "jdata="+json
String message = "jdata"+json; 
//And you didn't append it to the path either...
String path= "http://localhost/joomla/index.php?option=com_up1";
```

However, you should really be sending this in the message body.

Comment: I am now confused. The path is the url I want to send my message to.
Please elaborate more.
Thank you